# PIL Image "Wrong" Pixel Data (1,1,1) in Black and White Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I try to convert images to Data, for an array.
But sometimes in my compiled Code there are random wrong values.
I narrowed it down to wrong Pixel data, but I have no Idea why the Data has the Wrong Value
[Here an Image with the Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E6hN.jpg).
And my Code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

    #Open Image
img = Image.open('src.jpg')
pix = img.load()

    #Print Size of Image
print(img.size)

    #String of Pixels 
pixels = ""

    #Fill the String with the pixels
for py in range(0,img.size[1]):
    for px in range(0,img.size[0]):
        pixels+=str(pix[px,py])
    pixels+="\n"

    #Print the String
print(pixels)
```

Comment: Please post your source image `src.jpg` as imgur-link, so we can reproduce. Also adding the printed output as text to your question would help.

Comment: What is "wrong" in pixel-data `(1,1,1) ? What do you expect instead?

Comment: jpeg has lossy compression, that pixel may really be a dark gray one even if it was black at some point in the past

Comment: Why in your image looks like the bottom right square has an "inner" white square?

Comment: The Inner square is from Paint.net, I picked the colour with the pipette to show the values, but my mouse is not captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) in the comments, the reason your code does not work, and is almost identical to mine (see below), is that due to your image being in .JPG format is subject to a lot of compression, ending up in losing some pixel data. 
Your problem can therfore be fixed by using a .PNG format for the image that will preserve more pixel data compared to .JPG. 
At the end of this answer you can find the .PNG image that i used and that gave me the correct output(is attached to the answer, zoom in your web browser if you dont see anything, is **really small**).

This is the code I used:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('img.png')
pix = img.load()

pixels = ""
for p_y in range(0, img.size[1]):
    for p_x in range(0, img.size[0]):
        pixels+=str(pix[p_x, p_y])
    pixels += "\n"

print(pixels)
```

Giving me the output:

```
(0, 0, 0, 255)(0, 0, 0, 0)(0, 0, 0, 255)
(0, 0, 0, 0)(0, 0, 0, 255)(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The image i tested the code above is the following and has a resolution of (3x2 pixels), so is "like" the one you are showing in the link (you need to zoom **a lot** to see the image, yes is the little dot you see below here) but instead of being in .JPG is in .PNG:
[image: Test image]

.JPG zoomed version for sanity XD (upper right pixel is black is an artifact of .JPG, showing its limitations and also why you was having the issue)
[image]

Comment: TY for your answer :D

Comment: The answer would have been better if you had explained how it was different from the question code, and why you changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The critical point is the **Image compression of JPG.**
So using a **PNG** solves the problem, and the artefacts are gone.
Thanks for the answers :D